# strncpy only copying 16 bytes from one string to another

Tags: c, string, pass-by-reference

so I have this function that, for now, takes a string from a input.txt and passes it to a string str by reference using strncpy(). but when I've tried calling the string outside of the function, I dont get anything at all if it tries to copy more than 16 (15 with the '/0' at the end).

this is my function:

```c
int openFile(char *str){
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (arquivo == NULL){
        return 1; // couldnt open input.txt
    }

    fseek(arquivo, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(arquivo);
    rewind(arquivo);

    char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * size); // enough for 'size' chars
    size_t buffer_len = sizeof(char) * size; // sizeof(a) returns sizeof(a as pointer), so uh.. dont
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(a), size, buffer_len); // just to test what it's getting

    fgets(a, size + 1, arquivo);
    printf( "%s, %d" , a, size);

    realloc(str, sizeof(char) * size); // just in case there isnt enough space in str
    strncpy(str, a, 16); // error in THIS LINE doesnt copy more than 16 bytes
    // memmove(str, a, 16); //not a problem with strncpy, memmove gives the same problem
    // str[buffer_len - 1] = '\0';

    fclose(arquivo);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

my main is really simple too

```c
int main(){

    char *str;

    if(openFile(str)){ // if openFile return 1, error opening file
        printf("error opening file.\n");
        return 0;
    }
        
    printf("\n%s", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

and finally, the input/output (input = `MEEUMOCSHMSC1T*AGU0A***L2****T*****A`):

```
1 4 36 36
MEEUMOCSHMSC1T*AGU0A***L2****T*****A, 36
MEEUMOCSHMSC1T*A­
}
```

its a cypher, thats why input is so jambled;

that "}" at the end is part of the string I guess, it changes every time AND it dissapears when I substitute str[15] with '\0';

Comment: `fgets(a, size + 1, arquivo);` - this makes the program have undefined behavior if you read a string that is `size` characters long. It will then write the `\0` out of bounds. It should be `fgets(a, size, arquivo);` - You should also check the return value from `fgets`. It may return `NULL` to indicate failure.

Comment: i've tried that before, now the code doesnt get all 36 character (gets 35)... still same problem as before.

Comment: Ok, but at least you have one potential crash less.

Comment: You pass an unitialized pointer `str` into your function and put that "random" address into `realloc`. This is undefined behaviour. Initialize `str` to a valid address you receive from `malloc` or similar or to `NULL`. On top of that illegal pointer, you do not store the result of `realloc`. You should revisit the manual for that function. You could get a different memory address. Especially when you grow the memory.  Turn up warnings and read them.

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU'RE A GENIUS, THANK YOU

i mean, now the code get 20 characters instead of 16 but it increased

Comment: Also see what I added to previous comment.

Comment: **Check your return values!!** You also ignore return value of `fgets`. These values are not there just for entertainment.

Comment: `strncpy` is one of them inherently broken ancient C standard functions which should never be used for any purpose in modern C programming. See [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: Otávio Zampar, Tip: Enable all compiler warnings.  That will give you quick feedback concerning errors and weaknesses in you code.

Answer (score -1):

```
strncpy(str, a, 16);
```

```
strncpy(dest, src, length);
```

`length` is **maximum** number of `char`s copied. So it will not comply more than 16 `char`s in your case

Comment: yes, ideally I would put lenght as size (36 in that input) but when i do that i dont get ANY response from printf("\n%s", str);    so the max ends up beeing 16 (figured by brute force)